# How to get metadata pointer address for a token generated with Token program 2022

Tags: token-2022

I am trying to decode name and symbol for token mint 9ymawKvJmd3yeNpi6h3WaWvxkjQiGPW6od9ZTXZaVxGD. It's owner is token program 2022, this is a token from fluxbeam AMM.

It implements metadata extension, but first I need to find a way to retrive metadata pointer related to this Mint using RPC or js SDKs

How should this be done? I have not found a way using @solana/spl-token library

LIbrary versions in use:

"@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.9"
"solana/spl-token-metadata": "^0.1.2"

Code snippet:

```
    const Web3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
    const SplTokenMetadata = require("@solana/spl-token-metadata")
    const SplToken = require('@solana/spl-token');
    const connection = new Web3.Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed');

    const mint = new Web3.PublicKey("9ymawKvJmd3yeNpi6h3WaWvxkjQiGPW6od9ZTXZaVxGD");

    const mintInfo = await SplToken.getMint(
        connection,
        mint,
        "confirmed",
        SplToken.TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
    const metadataPointer = SplToken.getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
    console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

    // Extract and log the metadata
    const slicedBuffer = mintInfo.tlvData.subarray(72);
    const metadata = SplTokenMetadata.unpack(slicedBuffer);
    console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));

    console.log(metadataPointerState);
```

metadataPointer is always `null` and there is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@solana/spl-token-metadata`.

It would look something like this:

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  clusterApiUrl,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  getMint,
  getMetadataPointerState,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  createInitializeInstruction,
  createUpdateFieldInstruction,
  createRemoveKeyInstruction,
  unpack,
  pack,
  TokenMetadata,
} from "@solana/spl-token-metadata";
import { getOrCreateKeypair } from "./utils";

// Local Keypair for payer
// This is a custom helper, replace with a keypair that is funded with SOL
const wallet_1 = getOrCreateKeypair("wallet_1");

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Transaction to send
let transaction: Transaction;
// Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
let transactionSignature: string;

// Generate new keypair for Mint Account
const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
// Address for Mint Account
const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
// Decimals for Mint Account
const decimals = 2;
// Authority that can mint new tokens
const mintAuthority = wallet_1.publicKey;

const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
  updateAuthority: wallet_1.publicKey,
  mint: mint,
  name: "name",
  symbol: "symbol",
  uri: "uri",
  additionalMetadata: [["key1", "value1"]],
};

// Size of MetadataExtension 2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length
const metadataExtension = 4;
// Size of metadata
const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;

// Size of Mint Account with extension
const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.MetadataPointer]);

// Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
  mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
);

// Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
  fromPubkey: wallet_1.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
  newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
  space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
  lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
});

// Instruction to initialize the MetadataPointer Extension
const initializeMetadataPointerInstruction =
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
    mint, // Mint Account address
    wallet_1.publicKey, // Authority that can set the metadata address
    mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

// Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
  mint, // Mint Account Address
  decimals, // Decimals of Mint
  mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
  null, // Optional Freeze Authority
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
);

// Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
const initializeMetadataInstruction = createInitializeInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: wallet_1.publicKey, // Authority that can update the metadata
  mint: mint, // Mint Account address
  mintAuthority: wallet_1.publicKey, // Designated Mint Authority
  name: metaData.name,
  symbol: metaData.symbol,
  uri: metaData.uri,
});

// Instruction to update metadata, adding custom field
const updateFieldInstruction = createUpdateFieldInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: wallet_1.publicKey, // Authority that can update the metadata
  field: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0],
  value: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][1],
});

// Add instructions to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createAccountInstruction,
  initializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  initializeMintInstruction,
  initializeMetadataInstruction,
  updateFieldInstruction
);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [wallet_1, mintKeypair]
);

console.log(
  "\nCreate Mint Account:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

await fetchAndLogMintInfo();

// Instruction to remove a key from the metadata
const removeKeyInstruction = createRemoveKeyInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Address of the metadata
  updateAuthority: wallet_1.publicKey, // Authority that can update the metadata
  key: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // Key to remove from the metadata
  idempotent: true, /// If the idempotent flag is set to true, then the instruction will not error if the key does not exist
});

// Add instruction to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(removeKeyInstruction);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [wallet_1]
);

console.log(
  "\nRemove Additional Metadata Field:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

await fetchAndLogMintInfo();

async function fetchAndLogMintInfo() {
  // Retrieve mint information
  const mintInfo = await getMint(
    connection,
    mint,
    "confirmed",
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
  const metadataPointer = getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
  console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

  // Extract and log the metadata
  const slicedBuffer = mintInfo.tlvData.subarray(72);
  const metadata = unpack(slicedBuffer);
  console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));
}
```

For this specific example, the offset is 72 for where the metadata starts on the mint account.

```
  // Retrieve mint information
  const mintInfo = await getMint(
    connection,
    mint,
    "confirmed",
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
  const metadataPointer = getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
  console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

  // Extract and log the metadata
  const slicedBuffer = mintInfo.tlvData.subarray(72);
  const metadata = unpack(slicedBuffer);
  console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));
```

As mentioned in the [answer for this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8349/how-to-read-the-metadata-on-a-mint-account-created-using-the-metadata-interface),

> At the time of this writing, the Token Metadata extension for
> @solana/spl-token is still in development.
>
> However, once it's complete you'll be able to do this:
>
> const tokenMetadata = getTokenMetadataState(mintInfo);

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, but I just can't get it to work somehow, metadata pointer is always null:

Comment: if you look at the JSON tab of the data, your mint address doesn't have the metadata pointer extension enabled
https://solana.fm/address/9ymawKvJmd3yeNpi6h3WaWvxkjQiGPW6od9ZTXZaVxGD?cluster=mainnet-alpha

Comment: here's a devnet mint with the metadata pointer, and metadata stored on the mint account https://solana.fm/address/2J2edG94cHcG5Lp2ZYgFzp3E3uTVRMus1QywxZL9RMoU?cluster=devnet-solana