# How to parse SPL2022 Token Metadata back from the @solana/spl-token-metadata JS library?

Tags: spl-token

I'm trying to parse a mint-stored metadata as per the SPL Token 2022 Metadata extension (pointing to the mint itself).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
const mint = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(someAccount.mint);
  if (!mint) {
    throw new Error('Mint not found.');
  }
  const result = unpack(mint.data);
  return result;
```

But I get:

```
Error: Codec [string] expected 3844398571 bytes, got 387.
    at Object.assertByteArrayHasEnoughBytesForCodec
```

Which means unpacking the mint directly doesn't work, but I can't find anything on the Javascript tests that indicates me how to do it, any ideas?.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Solana Playground example](https://beta.solpg.io/658c5a75cffcf4b13384ceb5). Currently, reading the metadata requires identifying its location within the
mint account data. In the linked example, the Mint Account stores the metadata at
an offset of 72 bytes from the beginning of the `tlvData`. This offset might be different for you depending on the various extensions you have enabled.

```
// Retrieve mint information
const mintInfo = await getMint(
  connection,
  mint,
  "confirmed",
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);

// Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
const metadataPointer = getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

// Extract and log the metadata
const slicedBuffer = mintInfo.tlvData.subarray(72);
const metadata = unpack(slicedBuffer);
console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));
```

Based on the answer to [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8349/how-to-read-the-metadata-on-a-mint-account-created-using-the-metadata-interface), it
doesn't seem like there is a way to directly read the metadata at the moment.

Here is the full code from the Solana Playground example for reference.

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  clusterApiUrl,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  getMint,
  getMetadataPointerState,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  createInitializeInstruction,
  createUpdateFieldInstruction,
  createRemoveKeyInstruction,
  unpack,
  pack,
  TokenMetadata,
} from "@solana/spl-token-metadata";

// Playground wallet
const payer = pg.wallet.keypair;

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Transaction to send
let transaction: Transaction;
// Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
let transactionSignature: string;

// Generate new keypair for Mint Account
const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
// Address for Mint Account
const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
// Decimals for Mint Account
const decimals = 2;
// Authority that can mint new tokens
const mintAuthority = pg.wallet.publicKey;
// Authority that can update token metadata
const updateAuthority = pg.wallet.publicKey;

// Metadata to store in Mint Account
const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority,
  mint: mint,
  name: "OPOS",
  symbol: "OPOS",
  uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/opos-asset/main/assets/DeveloperPortal/metadata.json",
  additionalMetadata: [["description", "Only Possible On Solana"]],
};

// Size of MetadataExtension 2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length
const metadataExtension = 4;
// Size of metadata
const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;

// Size of Mint Account with extension
const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.MetadataPointer]);

// Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
  mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
);

// Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
  fromPubkey: payer.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
  newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
  space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
  lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
});

// Instruction to initialize the MetadataPointer Extension
const initializeMetadataPointerInstruction =
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
    mint, // Mint Account address
    updateAuthority, // Authority that can set the metadata address
    mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

// Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
  mint, // Mint Account Address
  decimals, // Decimals of Mint
  mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
  null, // Optional Freeze Authority
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
);

// Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
const initializeMetadataInstruction = createInitializeInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  mint: mint, // Mint Account address
  mintAuthority: mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
  name: metaData.name,
  symbol: metaData.symbol,
  uri: metaData.uri,
});

// Instruction to update metadata, adding custom field
const updateFieldInstruction = createUpdateFieldInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  field: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // key
  value: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][1], // value
});

// Add instructions to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createAccountInstruction,
  initializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  initializeMintInstruction,
  initializeMetadataInstruction,
  updateFieldInstruction
);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payer, mintKeypair] // Signers
);

console.log(
  "\nCreate Mint Account:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

// Retrieve mint information
const mintInfo = await getMint(
  connection,
  mint,
  "confirmed",
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);

// Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
const metadataPointer = getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

// Extract and log the metadata
const slicedBuffer = mintInfo.tlvData.subarray(72);
const metadata = unpack(slicedBuffer);
console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));

// Instruction to remove a key from the metadata
const removeKeyInstruction = createRemoveKeyInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Address of the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  key: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // Key to remove from the metadata
  idempotent: true, // If the idempotent flag is set to true, then the instruction will not error if the key does not exist
});

// Add instruction to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(removeKeyInstruction);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payer]
);

console.log(
  "\nRemove Additional Metadata Field:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

console.log(
  "\nMint Account:",
  `https://solana.fm/address/${mint}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);
```